# Does running a process in the background reduce its permissions?

Tags: linux, embedded

I am using an embedded system, which runs linux. When i run a compiled C program in the forground, it works correctly. However, when i add the '&' after the program call, to make it run as a job in the background, certain features do not work correctly. The main feature which stops working is the use of the 'read' function (unistd.h), used to read from a socket.

Does running a process in the backround reduce its permissions? 
What else could cause this behaviour?

Edit:
    The function uses the 'select' and 'read' function to read from a socket used for the reception of CANbus message frames. When the data is received, we analyse it and 'echo' a string into a .txt file, to act as a datalogger. When run in the foreground, the file is created and added to successfully, but when in the background, the file is not created/appended.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what stops working (perhaps showing some code, the output when the program is run in the foreground, and the output when the program is run in the background)?  As some answers have pointed out, the permissions don't change, but just getting the "no" answer won't really resolve your actual issue (or help those who run into it in the future).

Comment: While the answer to what you are describing is no, note that a process which the system (rather than a user) launches in the background will often have different permissions, primarily as it may get launched as a different userid.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, Thanks, that is useful to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only difference between running a process in foreground of background is the interaction with your terminal.

Typically when you background a process it's `stdin` gets disconnected (it no longer reads input from your keyboard) and you can no longer send keyboard-shortcut signals like Ctrl-C/Ctrl-D to the process.

Other then that nothing changes, no permissions or priorities are changed.

Comment: This is not fully correct - `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` are **not** disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

No, a process doesn't have its persmissons changed when going into background.

Answer (score 0):

Internally whats happening is before the process's code starts getting executed, the file descriptors 0,1,2 (stdin,out,err) will be pointed to /dev/null instead of usual files.

Similarly if you use `>/file/path` the `stdout` descriptor will point to that particular file

You can verify this with

```
ls -l /proc/process_number/fd
```

Comment: This is incorrect -  `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` are not disconnected, as examining the process's fd links in /proc will show.